# EF cannot map a foreign key

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am using code-first with MVC 5.2, EF 6.1.3 and SQL Server 2008 R2.

There are two tables: Item and Display. Item has a column called PreOrderDisplayID with a foreign key to Display.DisplayID.

In EF layer, I have:

```
class Item
    public int? PreOrderDisplayID { get; set; }
    public virtual Display PreOrderDisplay { get; set; }
...
class Display
    public int DisplayID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Item> PreOrderItems { get; set; }
...
class OrdersContext : DbContext
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Display>()
                .HasMany(e => e.PreOrderItems)
                .WithOptional(e => e.PreOrderDisplay)
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.PreOrderDisplayID);
}    
...
```

When I try to query this table via EF, I get:

> Invalid column name 'Display_DisplayID'.

and, I can see that under the covers, EF is generating SQL with a column that doesn't exist:

```
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Item] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ItemID] = [Extent2].[ItemID]
...
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Display] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent2].[Display_DisplayID] = [Extent5].[DisplayID]
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: show full class definitions for `Item` and `Display` as well as their full FLUENT configurations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that before I added PreOrderDisplay and PreOrderDisplayID to Item, there was already another relation in Item to Display via the Item.Display and Item.DisplayID properties. That relation was working fine without the HasForeignKey clause before, but once the new relation was added, I had to go to the original relation and add the HasForeignKey clause:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Display>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Items)
            .WithOptional(e => e.Display)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.DisplayID);
```